# Django/SQL - Creating a table view that joins a table with an override table

Tags: mysql, django-1.8

So I have the following model structure in my Django App:-

```
class SuperModel(models.Model):
    f1 = models.CharField()
    f2 = models.CharField()

class Model(SuperModel):
    f3 = models.CharField()

class OverrideModel(models.Model):
    fpk = models.OneToOneField(Model, primary_key=True)
    f1 = models.CharField()
    f2 = models.CharField()
```

Basically, in my application, the fields `f1` and `f2` in the `Model` table contain user information that I have entered. The user has the ability to override this information and any changes he/she makes in the data is stored in the `OverrideModel` table (because I do not want to lose the information that I had entered first). Think of it as me creating user profiles earlier while now I want the user to be able to edit his/her own profile without losing the information that I had entered about them.

Now, since the rest of my application (views/templates etal) work with the field names in the Model class, what I want is to create a **view** of the data that fetches the field `f1` from the override table if it exists, otherwise it should pickup `f1` from the table it used to earlier **without** resorting to a raw queryset.

I will describe everything I have considered so far so that some of the other constraints I am working with become clear:-

1. `Model.objects.annotate(f1=Case(When(overridemodel__f1__isnull=True, then=F('f1')), default=F('overridemodel__f1')))`.

   This throws the error that the annotate alias conflicts with a field already in the table.
2. `Model.objects.defer('f1').extra(select={'f1': 'CASE WHEN ... END'}, tables=..., where=...)`.

   This approach cannot be applied because I could not figure out a way to apply an outer join using extra. The override model may not have a row corresponding to each model row. Specifying the override table in the `tables` clause performs a cross product operation which combined with where can be used to perform an inner join, not an outer join (although I'd be happy to be proved wrong).

   **EDIT**: I have realized that select_related might be able to solve the above problem but if I filter the queryset generated by `Model.objects.select_related('overridemodel').defer('f1').extra(select={'f1': 'CASE WHEN ... END'}, tables=..., where=...)` on the field `f1`, say `qs.filter(f1='Random stuff')` the where clause for the filter query uses the `Model.f1` field rather than the `f1` field generated in extra. So this approach is also futile.
3. Using `Model.objects.raw()` to get a raw queryset.

   This is a non-starter because the Django ORM becomes useless after using `raw` and I need to be able to filter / sort the model objects as part of the application.
4. Defining methods/properties on the `Model` class.

   Again, I will not be able to use the same field names here which involves hunting through code for all usages and making changes.
5. Creating a view in the database that gives me what I want and creating an unmanaged model that reads the data from that view.

   This is probably the best solution for my problem but having never used an unmanaged model before, I'm not sure how to go about it or what pitfalls I might encounter. One problem that I can think of off the top of my head is that my view always has to be kept in sync with the models but that seems a small price to pay compared to hunting through the codebase and making changes and then testing to see if anything broke.

So, there you have it. As always, any help / pointers will be greatly appreciated. I have tried to provide as minimal an example as possible; so if any more information is required I'll be happy to provide it.

Also, I am using Django 1.8 with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that there is no easy canonical way to solve my problem. Even with using option 5 (creating a view that is ORM manipulated using an unmanaged Model), I would lose the related query names on the original model that are being used in my filtering / sorting.

So, for anyone else with a similar problem I would recommend the approach I finally went with which is not keeping an OverrideModel but an OverriddenModel which keeps the values that are overridden whenever the user makes changes and updating the original Model with the override values so that the model always contains the values on which filtering / querying is going to occur